# Productimg.php errorlog in system.log

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-swatches, magento1.9.3.7

I update Magento from 1.9.3.0 to 1.9.3.7

magento log this error in system.log

> Warning: array_merge_recursive() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given
>   in
>   /home/example/domains/example.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Productimg.php
>   on line 336 2018-12-10T08:05:18+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_unique()
>   expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in
>   /home/example/domains/example.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Helper/Productimg.php
>   on line 337

and this is the function in Productimg.php

```
 public function filterImageInGallery($product, $image)
    {
        if (!Mage::helper('configurableswatches')->isEnabled()) {
            return true;
        }

        if (!isset($this->_productImageFilters[$product->getId()])) {
            $mapping = call_user_func_array("array_merge_recursive", $product->getChildAttributeLabelMapping());
            $filters = array_unique($mapping['labels']);
            $filters = array_merge($filters, array_map(function ($label) {
                return $label . Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Productimg::SWATCH_LABEL_SUFFIX;
            }, $filters));
            $this->_productImageFilters[$product->getId()] = $filters;
        }

        return !in_array(Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Helper_Data::normalizeKey($image->getLabel()),
            $this->_productImageFilters[$product->getId()]);
    }
```

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the attribute you're using to allow selection of a simple product is included in the **Product Attributes to Show as Swatches in Product Detail** list in **System > Configuration > Configurable Swatch**